# Remove comma from variable in CMD

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, pid, tasklist

How are you all doing?

I made a batch file that gets the memory usage of a process that has a specific PID...
Here is the code:

```
@Echo off

REM Get memory from process using tasklist
for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %A in ('tasklist /svc /fi "SERVICES eq .Service02" /FO csv /NH') do ( 
    REM Store PID on a variable
    @Set "pidSlv02=%~A"
    REM Get memory usage from process with that PID
    for /f "tokens=5 delims= " %B in ('tasklist /fi "pid eq %pidSlv02%" /NH') do (
    REM Store mem value on another variable
    @Set "memSlv02=%~B"
    REM Remove commas from variable
    @Echo %memSlv02% K
    )
)
```

So, the output is:

> 1,407,356

Now, i need to convert that number to be 1407356

I did not come here directly. I already tried a couple of things but without success.
Im still very new and learning CMD/batch scripts... Didnt even know t was possible to do so much on Windows. Thought it was only possible on Linux. So please don't be angry with me if i dont understand something. Im trying my best!

Also, sorry if i mispelled something here since this is not my native language.

I tried adding the code:

```
set memSlv02=!memSlv02:,=!
set /a total=!total! + !memSlv02!
```

But if i use echo %total% i receive Missing operator. 0

Any tips?

Comment: Have you tried `echo !total!`?

Comment: Delayed Expansion still needs to be enabled in your code with the `SETLOCAL` command. Otherwise the exclamation points are treated just like a string character.  `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`.

Comment: Also your code as posted does not execute in a batch file per the help file for the `FOR` command. **To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead
of %variable.**

Comment: `for /f "tokens=2* delims=="  %i in ('wmic service where "name =".Service02"" get ProcessID /value ^|find/i"process"') do @wmic process where ProcessID=%i get WorkingSetSize`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's is an example which should output the data you require using the commands you've decided are best for you!

```sh
@Echo Off & SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "SvcName=.Service02"
For /F Tokens^=3^ Delims^=^" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe
 /Fi "Services Eq %SvcName%" /Fo CSV /NH /Svc 2^>NUL') Do Set "PID=%%G"^
 & For /F Tokens^=9^ Delims^=^" %%H In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe
 /Fi "PID Eq %%G" /Fo CSV /NH 2^>NUL') Do Set "MemKB=%%H"^
 & SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion & For /F %%I In ("!MemKB:,=!") Do EndLocal^
 & Set "MemKB=%%I"
Echo %%SvcName%% = %SvcName%, %%PID%% = %PID%, %%MemKB%% = %MemKB% & Pause
```

You would obviously replace the last line which I've included just to show you the defined variables. I have made it simple to just replace the Service Name on line two, should you wish to do so, but nothing else should be modified at all.

*BTW, I will not be explaining how any of the above works, so I advise that you perform further reasearch should you feel the need to understand it, but cannot currently do so.*

Comment: Oh! Thanks man! I took this part of your code: F"or /F %%I In ("!MemKB:,=!") Do EndLocal^ & Set "MemKB=%%I"" and changed accordingly in the code i already had and it worked like a charm... I believe that the part that removes comma is !MemKB:,=! ? Thanks for giving me a straight answer! I couldnt get this to work before your answer, now my code is working perfectly <3